# HTML - CSS Rotate Div is Not Rotated 180 Deg

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add Fill animation from bottom to top of the box `.box-inner-1` but CSS Rotate is not working properly!

```js
$('.box-inner-1').css({
  top: '0'
}).animate({
  "height": 260
}, 4000);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 260px;
  width: 260px;
  padding: 0px !important;
  background: #ddd;
}
.box-inner-1 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: greenyellow;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  transform: rotate(-180deg);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box-inner-1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add `border-top:1px solid #f00` to your `.box-inner-1`.  The rotate is working.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the box to animate from the bottom to top by changing `top: '0'` to `bottom: '0'`.

```js
$('.box-inner-1').css({
  bottom: '0'
}).animate({
  "height": 260
}, 4000);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 260px;
  width: 260px;
  padding: 0px !important;
  background: #ddd;
}
.box-inner-1 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: greenyellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box-inner-1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lots Kathy, this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Check transform-origin : center

Answer (score 0):

In fact it *is*  rotated, but right from the beginning - see my snippet, where I added some content to that DIV which is displayed upside down. Not sure what you expact - the rotation isn't animated, in case you expacted that - you don't set that anywhere (?)

```js
$('.box-inner-1').css({
  top: '0'
}).animate({
  "height": 260
}, 4000);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 260px;
  width: 260px;
  padding: 0px !important;
  background: #ddd;
}
.box-inner-1 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: greenyellow;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  transform: rotate(-180deg);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box-inner-1">look here</div>
</div>
```